# How to write a script to control the projector and cameras connected on the computer?

Tags: opencv, ip-camera, projector

I am doing some stereo vision experiment, but I have no idea how to set up thoese equipments.

Is there any module in openCV that I can use the control the projector to project any image any time I want? Similarly, how can I control a camera to capture any time I want by codes, or set up a window and recieve the live video captured from the camera?

Is there any framwork or something is designed for this?

By the way, my system is windows.

I have tried google, but there is little information on this, only a win32 tutorial from MS seems talking about accessing the projector connected to the computer. Maybe I have little experience on hardware programming and search the wrong way?

Comment: you're being too specific. projector or regular display, makes no difference. you want to show something on "the screen". -- you know of opencv. how about you work through the official tutorials. they'll show you how to show an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really so many user-friendly options out there.

With OpenCV it is possible, but you need to write some code to control the projector (which is seen as a display). You have to project the pattern(s) that you like and capture the images from the camera.
For this part, I wrote my own code and you're free to try it [here](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/master/examples/102%20Cam-Proj%20capture.py), although it might not work on your system.

Then, the next step is to process the images with the chosen structured light algorithm. You can find other useful code in the same [library](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStere).

Unless you buy a commercial system, programming knowledge is indispensable.

Good luck with your experiments.

Comment: where did this "structured light" idea come from? OP doesn't mention any of that. granted, "stereo" and "projector" often imply that someone's trying to project structured light, but that's extrapolated a bit much. OP merely wants to show images and read from a camera. telling them to read tutorials/docs is all that can be done.

Comment: You're right, I just assumed this. Anyway the example linked is general and can be used for projecting any image and capturing from the camera. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you Christoph and decadenza, my experiment indeed is about structured light. And I have figured out that the functions I need are `videoCapture` for camera and `imshow` for projector.